# One Win7 computer, 2 NICs, two networks

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter

I have the following layout:

A windows 7 Pro workstation with 2 NICs as described below:

NIC #1: IP static address 10.0.0.1, Subnet mask 255.0.0.0 with no gateway. The computer connects to a CMM machine. The CMM manufacturer establish these settings for the PC communicating with the machine.

NIC #2: DHCP, DNS server 10.0.0.2 The "implicit" subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 and the gateway is 10.0.0.1 it connects to the LAN. The gateway is our router.

Right now they conflict. How should I configure both NICs to work properly?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 networks overlap with each other.  If possible, use a different subnet for the CMM machine.  For example, 192.168.0.1 for the CMM machine and 192.168.0.2 for NIC #1 on the Windows PC.

A different solution would be to put the CMM machine on your regular network (connect it directly to your switch) and either let it get a dynamic address, or a static one that's outside your DHCP scope.  That advantage of doing that way is:

1. Any other PC on the network could also access the CMM machine
2. Your Windows PC only needs one NIC

I had a similar situation with an Epilog laser cutter (the manufacturer wanted it connected like you described in your question), but I went with soliution #2 and it works great.

Comment: Charles, thank you much for your prompt advice. I agree with your first assertion, they overlap. Being on the same subnet and actually having the same IP address as my LAN gateway, it seems pretty logical that is occurring. I wonder why the CMM has to have be  in the same LAN range and not a 192.168.x.x. I"ll check the point with the provider.

Comment: Sorry about the confusing wording. Your solution won't fit in our case because only the computer directly attached to the CMM has the software to communicate with it. It's an alternative solution to try though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I strongly suspect that any subnet will work just fine for the CMM machine, but yes, check with the vendor or manufacturer.  In Solution #2, I understand that the PC needs special software, but if you ever need to have a second PC access the CM machine, then it's just a matter of installing the software and you're good to go.